# Given a real $x$ and an integer $N > 1$, prove that there exist integers $h$ and $k$ with $0 < k \leq N$ such that $|kx − h| < 1/N$.

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone solve this question?

> Given a real $x$ and an integer $N > 1$, prove that there exist integers $h$ and $k$ with $0 < k \leq N$ such that $|kx − h| < 1/N$.
>
> **Hint.** Consider the $N + 1$ numbers $tx − [tx]$ for $t = 0, 1, 2, ..., N$, and show that some pair differs by at most $1/N$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your question comes with a fine hint.  Do what it says.